# PHP output buffering (ob_start, ob_flush)

Tags: php, exe, flush, output-buffering, ob-start

I used php output buffering earlier in order to create csv file from database, because i didn't want to create an existing file, just wanted to make content downloadable.

CSV is text-based file, so its easy to create this way, you set the header and flush the text content. But! What if, I want to create an exe from hex data? (The project is: I have an existing exe file and I want that users can write something inside a HTML textbox and I convert that to hex and exchange the old text to the new one)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what range of bytes in exe file you want to overwrite?

Comment: i do. its about 100-200 bytes in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace part of binary file, for example from 100th byte to 200th byte you could use substr() and str_pad():

```
$binFile = file_get_contents('/pathto/exec/file.exec');
$replacedBinFile = substr($binFile, 0, 100) . str_pad(substr($_POST['text'], 0, 100), 100, "\x00") . substr($binFile, 200);
file_put_contents('/pathto/exec/file_replaced.exec', $replacedBinFile);
```

Comment: and isnt it possible to read all of the hexadecimal datas from my database (not from the exe) and i create a string and flush it to exe?

Comment: Php substr() is binary safe and operates on bytes not on characters. String in php are also a sequences of bytes. So it does not matter from where you have your data if it's a php string. It can be from database, $_POST, xml, whatever. I don't really get what do you mean by "hexadecimal data". Can you explain more?

Answer (score 3):

Use following code to download exe file by reading from hard disk.

```
<?php
$file = 'test.exe';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: but is it hex-based? cuz' i have to replace the bytes.

Comment: you have an exe now, that you read and make it downloadable, BUT i have to get hexadecimal content from the exe and exchange 100-200 bytes in it with ANOTHER hexadecimal content somehow.

Comment: you can use file_get_contents to read file contents and can replace some from it. I've never tried this but it seems possible by using this.